# How to replace part of filename recursively in terminal / .zsh?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

how can I replace a part of the filename, of a certain type (.zip), with another string, recursively through all potential nested subdirectories?

**This is my filesystem structure:**

```
dir/
   |
   subdir/
   |
   filename_strToReplace.zip
   |
   subdir/
         |
         subdir
              |
              filename_strToReplace.zip
              filename_strToReplace.zip
              filename_strToReplace.zip
```

So as you can see, files whose filenames need to be modiffied can be nested few levels deep. I have some moderate terminal and shell experience but not real scripting.

I believe the solution is the combination of `mv`, RegEx (which I can use pretty decently) and a `for` loop.

For what it's worth I am on a Mac, using "default" terminal (haven't messed with this) with Oh-my-zshell.

Thanks!

Comment: I apologise but frankly I am quite new to the console so I must be confusing terminal, terminal program, shell and quite possibly other basic terminology (Off topic: if you have a good starter tutorial on these, please let me know. Cheers!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) commands you can achieve that:

```
find . -name '*strToReplace*' | xargs -I{} rename 's/strToReplace/replacement/' {}
```

**find** search all files whose name contains *strToReplace*.
Then **rename** uses a regex to rename those files.

Comment: Hey, I got this: `~> xargs: rename: No such file or directory`

Comment: You might have to install it, probably using Homebrew

Comment: This is overkill for `zsh`.

Comment: What does the pipe-to-xargs do and what is the -I switch? :) The rest I understand completely. (Why didn't you use -exec rename for example?

Comment: There is no particular reason to not use -exec, it should work the same. The '-I' switch replaces occurrences of  '{}'  in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input (i.e: files found with find)

Comment: As chepner mentioned, the answer is not zsh specific, it is a more general solution using gnu/bsd tools.

Comment: Using only `rename` (and adding `-n` for a dry run, remove it for a live run): `rename -n 's/strToReplace/replacement/' **/*strToReplace*`

Answer (score 4):

Use `zmv`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -n '(dir/**/filename)_(.*).zip' '($1)_replacementStr.zip'
```

Remove the `-n` to actually perform the rename after verifying that the command will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` you could achieve this using `find` + a custom function

```
#!/bin/bash
function namereplacer()
{
for file in "$@"
do
 mv "$file" "${file/%stringToReplace.zip/newstring.zip}"
done

}
export -f namereplacer
find /base/path/ -depth -type f -name "*stringToReplace.zip" \
-exec bash -c 'namereplacer "$@"' _ {} + 
# The 'exec {} +' form builds the command line, see find man
```

---

<sup>**Note** Replace `/base/path` with your path to base folder</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I used rename similar to sjsam's answer to create a shell script.  My use case was to remove `.bak` extension from the end of the first filename that matched the `.tsx` pattern:

```
dir=$1
extensionToChange=.bak
for file in $(find $dir -type f -name *.tsx$extensionToChange); do
  echo $file
  mv "$file" "${file/$extensionToChange/}"
  break;
done
```

Had to grant execute permission on the script with `chmod +x rename_first.sh`

Example execution: `./rename_first.sh ../UI/test/src`